# Calabash testing on Jenkins build server

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, calabash, calabash-ios

I am coming at this problem as a complete newbie with regards to configuring Jenkins build jobs. I can just about understand what is going on at this moment.

I have local calabash tests running correctly and my project is setup according to this way: [Link](http://fangmobile.com/2014/05/08/do-you-love-calabash-ios-but-hate-that-cal-second-target/) where a new Scheme is created to run the tests against.

I really don't know where to start looking to get the tests running on Jenkins. Do I need to get cucumber installed on the build server first or can this be done as part of the build steps? I ask this because the command to start the tests is `DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber`.

A point in the right direction for a tutorial is all I ask for.

Comment: Hey Sam, I'm running calabash tests on both iOS and android simulators over an year as jenkins nightly builds and tests. If you have any problems please specifically mention the questions and steps. I'm happy to help you anytime. cheers.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have got the tests to run locally as part of a build job the next stage is to get it configured with the Jenkins build server but i'm holding off at the moment. Do you have any experience in running the tests in different languages/locales?

Comment: sorry , no experience in different languages. You can use additional layer to select locale in step files.

Answer (score 1):

First of about installing calabash manually or when tests are executed. You should be able to handle that by using "bundle" where you define what gems are needed.
However over time you might find that you like to be able to manage what versions of the gems you are running. So manually install might be preferable.

As for running the tests you will need to use a slightly different approach. You would probably like to output to a file to be able to show result after test, instead of just outputting to console.

You could take a look here and see if this guide helps you http://blog.watchlaterapp.com/blog/2013/03-Calabash-iOS-Jenkins.html

Otherwise more concrete questions will be easier for community to answer.

I hope it helps you.